# How do I avoid overriding a key from a global dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

**I'm using the command line arguments as user input...**

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import csv, argparse
from collections import defaultdict

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-p", dest='prodfile', action="append", help="file names for prod")
args = parser.parse_args()

files_d={}
files_d[""]=[]

if args.testfile:
    testfile = args.testfile
    type_file="test"
    files_d[type_file]=testfile

if args.prodfile:
   prodfile = args.prodfile
   type_file="prod"
   files_d[type_file]=prodfile

print files_d
```

**how do I avoid overriding [type_file] on all dictionaries??**

**EDIT**  The core question is how to accumulate a list of values that shared the same key (in this case, `type_file` is the repeated key with `testfile` and `prodfile` both needing to be accumulated in a list.

Comment: This is very unclear. What are you concerned about overriding? You only set the "test" and "prod" keys, and don't override anything.

Comment: What are **all** dictionnaries? There is only `files_d`, isn't it?

Comment: Your program produces "`AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'testfile'`". Please copy-paste an exact program that we can run, and include the output you see along with the output you expected to see.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm running this program through the command line

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm supposed to be adding multiple files not just 2 with either the "prod or test" keys. When I do that, the other keys all end up being "prod".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the dictionary keys are unique, so any subsequent assignment to the same key will **replace** rather than **add to** the dict value.  What you need is for the key to may to a **list of matching values**.

A [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a *list()* factory function should meet your needs:

```
from collections import defaultdict     # <== new code

files_d = defaultdict(list)             # <== new code
files_d[""]=[]

if args.testfile:
    testfile = args.testfile
    type_file="test"
    files_d[type_file].append(testfile) # <== new code

if args.prodfile:
   prodfile = args.prodfile
   type_file="prod"
   files_d[type_file].append(prodfile)  # <== new code
```

Good luck.  Hope this solves your issue regarding `[type_file]` overriding values (replacing them) instead of appending to a list of matching values.

Comment: it is still overriding all of the keys so that they all say "prod", I'm certain it has to do with the fact that the line type_file="prod" is within the if statement. Do you know how i get around that so that I'm not overriding and just appending?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as follows:

```
if args.testfile:
    testfile = args.testfile
    type_file="test"
    if files_d.get(type_file):
        files_d[type_file].append(testfile)
    else:
        files_d[type_file] = list(type_file)


if args.prodfile:
   prodfile = args.prodfile
   type_file="prod"
   if files_d.get(type_file):
        files_d[type_file].append(testfile)
    else:
        files_d[type_file] = list(type_file)

print files_d
```